# how to add a file to every page just before </html> magento

Tags: javascript, magento, footer

In magento i would like to add a file like facebook.phtml to the bottom of every page just before the  including a simple javascript file

What is the best end most simple way to get this done ?

Comment: I have never user magento. Can you load a magento file? It is common approach to implement a footer and use the same footer in all pages for other technologies.

Answer (score 1):

i created a static block in the magento admin and add it to the bottom of my pages with a local.xml file like:

```
<cms_page>
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="cms/block" name="cms_facebook_code">
            <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>facebook_code</block_id></action></block>        
 </reference>
</cms_page>
```

Comment: This is definitely the correct way to do it. Note that this will add the block to all CMS pages. Alternatively, you may want to add it to all pages altogether (use the `default` layout handle instead of `cms_page`), or specific CMS pages (use the Layout Update XML field in the admin for the CMS page).